# How to display current month as text

Tags: javascript

I've got a site with a table that displays the month in text. I've been having to update it myself each month manually.

How do I get the current month as text with JavaScript so I don't have to update it manually?

Comment: A good place to start is to post what you already have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the current month as text

```
var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
                  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var d = new Date();
var currentMonth = monthNames[d.getMonth()];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the method `getMonth` of Date.

```
var date = new Date();
var month = date.getMonth();
```

Pay attention that `getMonth` returns an integer number in the range [0,11]. So January is 0 and December is 11.

Using this method you can get the current month. The way you will make the update depends on your code.

Comment: Is there a way to make it text? Or do I have to set each number up with a text month?